# I need to code an email input with the submit button directly to the right (image included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create an input slot/button side by side like so.

They need to be responsive to the size of the browser (35px margin on both sides). This is for a mobile site.

[image]

How do I make this?

Comment: sorry i'm new to this... this is what i have tried                                                          <div id="emailcont">

<div id="input"></div>
<div id="submit"></div>

</div>

Comment: and for the css I tried using block item and display inline but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: You need to stype your buttons like so: feel free to style them more inside.
working code at: http://jsfiddle.net/73DD2/2/

Fields:

```
<input type="text"value="email address"><input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Style:

```
input[type="text"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    left: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 34px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add `margin: 36px` it is added to the web as well as mobile sites!

You can try this:

First create a parent element as:

```
<div class="parent">
   <input type="text" name="field" />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>
```

Now, use this:

```
.parent {
   margin: 0 35px;
   // you donot need to write the width and height properties for this
}

input[type="text"] {
  max-width: 60%; // 60% of the parent element
}

input[type="submit"] {
  max-width: 40%; // 40% of the parent element..
}
```

The margin would be applied to the parent element (`.parent`) and the input would be displayed inline using

```
input[type="text"], input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline;
}
```

This one is a simple, but easy to understand example for you! Since you are a beginner you might need to read some documentations from https://developer.mozilla.org/, http://msdn.microsoft.com and many more...

here is a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/t88Wm/. Sorry for low quality styles, I forgot to add `border-radius`.

CSS styles are as:

```
parent {
   margin: 0 35px;
    background-color: #cecece;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  max-width: 60%; /* 60% of the parent element */
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #999;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  max-width: 40%; /* 40% of the parent element..*/
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not look anything like what he showed in his example above. More css coding would be required inorder to get your code to look like his example.

Comment: Ok! :) Wait for just a ummm 2 minutes please, I will create the CSS

Comment: @user3105072 you are most welcome, look for the editted answer now! :) It is working and has a fiddle too :)

Comment: @DenverWilliam, you can see the fiddle in my code, and please don't mention the `border-radius` now! -_-

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan this still looks nothing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/73DD2/, did you see his example above? He was not just looking for two side by side, that is easy, he was looking for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code using JQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/fbf4s/4/

```
var s=$(window).width()-70;  // 35+35=70 for margin
document.getElementById("parent").style.width = s+"px";

// for maintaining margin while resizing
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var s=$(window).width()-70;
    document.getElementById("parent").style.width = s+"px";
});
```